# How to play Next song Automatically when First one is finish?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, audio-streaming

In my app I am using AudioStreamer to play a song through server,

I am refering this tutorial,

http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/09/streaming-and-playing-live-mp3-stream.html

How to play next song Automatically when using AudioStreamer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer,

In that tutorial there isplaybackStateChanged:(NSNotification *)aNotification method,

```
    - (void)playbackStateChanged:(NSNotification *)aNotification
    {
    if ([songStreamer isWaiting])
   {

   }
       if ([songStreamer isPlaying])
   {

   }
   else if ([songStreamer isIdle])
   {
         [self playnextsong];

   }

      else if ([songStreamer isPaused])
  {

  }
}
```

When song completes through streaming,
It going to idle state.
So in idle state i call a method of playing next song.

And it Runs.

Comment: Please accept your own answer if it works. Also I would like to know whether it runs when we are not able to play a stream because of some parsing problem? I think then too it will go to idle state.

Answer (score 0):

In the tutorial is mentioned callback function which is triggered when a song finish playing. Your goal is to write functionality for your list of songs to move on the next one when this function is called.

```
void MyAudioQueueIsRunningCallback( void *                  inClientData,
                         AudioSessionPropertyID inID,
                         UInt32                  inDataSize,
                         const void *            inData)
{
move to the next song
}
```